# i was adding offocial SQLite source code to my C++ project and gets a linker error

Tags: c++, sqlite, linker

What sort of linking error is this referring to within my C++ project?  The only thing that i am thinking of is that the SQLite3 header is a part of the project.

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
/Users/.../Build/Intermediates/AssetInspector.build/Debug-iphoneos/AssetInspector.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main.o
/Users/.../Build/Intermediates/AssetInspector.build/Debug-iphoneos/AssetInspector.build/Objects-normal/armv7/shell.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the function main is defined both in main.c and shell.c.

You should only link with one of those object files from those .c files and not both

Comment: Oh?   Yea, I guess there is a demo project that i might've accidently imported.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling the SQLite amalgamation into your project, use *only* the `sqlite3.c` file.
The other files are not needed.
(`shell.c` is the source code of the `sqlite3` command-line tool.)